# VBScript to copy one file to multiple destinations and show gui progress bar

Tags: vbscript, copy, progress-bar

I am trying to create a VBScript that will copy one file to multiple UNC-destinations simultaneously and display Windows Explorer progress bar while doing so.

I am new to VBScripting and so far I am only able to copy one file using this code:

```
Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0&

strTargetFolder = "\\computer\target"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strTargetFolder)

objFolder.CopyHere "C:\tmp\copy\*.*", FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
```

How can I add another destination and display two progress bars?

Comment: By doing the last line twice.

Comment: @Noodles That will only copy the same file to the same destination over again and ask if I want to replace the file already beeing there. I want multiple destinations with the same file simultaneously.

Comment: One assumed you had some smarts to change the destination on each line.

Comment: Note I need them to run simultaneously and not once the other has finished.

Comment: VBScript is single threaded.

Comment: Write your copy commands into `.bat` files and run them using a `WScript.Shell` object; as close to simultaneous execution as you'll get with vbscript

Comment: You can arrange multiprocess VBScript environment to make it simultaneously.