# How to copy with default copier from cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, copy

I need to copy files from one folder to another from cmd and show the progress as in the user interface.
The copy and xcopy commands work but do not show progress and robocopy shows the progress but not the user interface. 
Explorer.exe has some parameters, but none that works to copy.
Do you know any way to do what I need?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: There is no built-in command that does this. Would a external script be acceptable?

Comment: Maybe it works for me, how do I do it?

Comment: Script in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945142/vbscript-to-copy-one-file-to-multiple-destinations-and-show-gui-progress-bar) will do exactly what you want. Just save it in file with `vbs` extension and edit accordingly to your needs

Comment: I think I can work with the previous example, thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in command that does this, you have to use Windows Scripting Host or a 3rd-party application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><job><script language="JScript"><![CDATA[
var SHA = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
if (WScript.Arguments.length != 2)
{
    WScript.Echo("Usage: <SourceSpec> <DestinationPath>");
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
var src = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(0)), dst = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(1));
var folder = SHA.NameSpace(dst);
var FOF_NOCONFIRMATION=0x0010;
var FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR=0x0200;
folder.CopyHere(src, FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR);
]]></script></job>
```

Save as `shellcopy.wsf` in %WinDir%.

Then in cmd.exe you can do `shellcopy *.txt c:\backup` etc.